# Facebook long lived token

Tags: facebook

I am using my facebook application to log the user into a android application. I use the following URL

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

to exchange my initial short lived token for a long lived token. By hitting the URL with my app settings, i get a new access token but the expires_in time remains the same around 1.5 hours ? What can i do to get a token that expires in 60 days ? Each time i hit this URL, the expires is sightly decreased. What am i doing wrong ?

Kind Regards

Comment: Are you doing this from within your android app? Since this call contains your app secret, it should only be made server-side (as the documentation explicitly states as well).

Comment: I am testing this from within advanced rest client. I dont think it should make a difference.